# Optimizing some code whose purpose is for better UI

Tags: jquery

How would you rewrite this?  It works, but it has been thrown together.  Purpose: If you click anywhere within a td element that contains a checkbox, then the checkbox is selected.

```
$('td input').filter(':checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('td').addClass('CursorPointer');
});
$('td.CursorPointer').click(function() {
    $('input:checkbox',this).click();
});
$('input:checkbox').click(function(myEvent) {
    myEvent.stopPropagation();
});
```

I wonder if this is a good example of adding an event listener, or using the delegate method.

Comment: Could you make a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) out of this, with some actual html? Easier to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('td').has(':checkbox').addClass('CursorPointer').click(function(e) {
    $('input:checkbox',this).click();
}).find(':checkbox').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gislikonrad/5G7ee/

Answer (score 2):

**First:**

```
$('td input').filter(':checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).closest('td').addClass('CursorPointer');
});
```

Is the same as:

```
 $('td').has(':checkbox').addClass('CursorPointer');
```

**Secondly** Similar to **sdleihssirhc** but targeting a specific element (best not to overload document with too many bubbling events).

```
$('#my-table-id').delegate('.CursorPointer', 'click', function () {
    $(':checkbox', this).click();
}).delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: First: I think you copied the wrong code from the OP... Second: you don't have a second point...

Answer (score 1):

The `.click` method in jQuery attaches a click event listener to every single element in the matched group, so yeah, it would probably be a little more efficient if you changed both of those to use event delegation:

```
$(document).delegate('td.CursorPointer', 'click', function () {
    $('input:checkbox', this).click();
}).delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', function (myEvent) {
    myEvent.stopPropagation();
});
```

There's probably a very slightly more efficient way to phrase that in jQuery, but that's the essential idea.

Comment: I always forget about delegate... +1

Comment: Applying delegate to the `document` will most likely be less performant if the document gets more and more delegates. Best to target a specific element such as `$('#my-table').delegate(`